# What to do about avoiding serialization exceptions on potential malformed JSON input due to extra escape characters

Tags: java, json, gson, json-deserialization

I am using GSON to convert a stringified JSON object into a POJO I have defined. The JSON is very large but the POJO is a small subset of those properties. The original JSON has some properties whose values themselves are stringified JSON objects, so you have something like

```
{
   "someAttribute": "{\"foo\": [{\"bar\"}]}"
}
```

This is a very simplified example. The actual JSON is much more nested and much larger.

Now when testing, I tried passing in a stringified version of the large json using JSON.stringify from my browser, which resulted in all `\"` sequences becoming `\\"`. I the subsequently pasted the string into IntelliJ, which then converted the `\\"` sequences to `\\\\\"`. When GSON tried to serialize this, it threw a malformed JSON exception.

Although I believe this to be an intellij issue of adding extra escape characters (once I changed `\\\\\"` to `\\\"` it worked fine), It occurred to me that if my function were to receive improperly escaped JSON due to possible differences in stringification, GSON would throw an exception. I don't know how any serialization package would know what is the correct or incorrect number of escape characters, but given that the actual JSON structure itself is not malformed, what can I do to avoid "false positive" JSON serialization issues?

Comment: Not much. Improper encoding is improper encoding. In this case, IntelliJ was "helpfully" encoding your encoded JSON for embedding in your Java source code. That is not something your end users are likely to do often.

Comment: The example you give is a string containing an unescaped `"`. Surely throwing an exception in that instance isn't a "false positive"?

Comment: @tgdavies that was a typo, i fixed it. my mistake.